# How to create list of numbers and append its reverse to it efficiently in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

Given a minimum integer and maximum integer, I want to create an array which counts from the minimum to the maximum by two, then back down (again by two, repeating the maximum number).

For example, if the minimum number is 1 and the maximum is 9, I want `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]`.

I'm trying to be as concise as possible, which is why I'm using one-liners.

In Python, I would do this:

```
range(1, 10, 2) + range(9, 0, -2)
```

In Ruby, which I'm just beginning to learn, all I've come up with so far is:

```
(1..9).inject([]) { |r, num| num%2 == 1 ? r << num : r }.reverse.inject([]) { |r, num| r.unshift(num).push(num) }
```

Which works, but I know there **must** be a better way.  What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(1..9).step(2).to_a + (1..9).step(2).to_a.reverse
```

But shorter would be

```
Array.new(10) { |i| 2 * [i, 9-i].min + 1 }
```

if we're code golfing :)

Comment: Oh, how could I forget `Range#step`!

Comment: Range#step seems to [expect a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000695) - the first example, while otherwise exactly what I was hoping for, is throwing an error for me.  (`no block given (LocalJumpError)`)

Comment: @Kiwi: You're using Ruby 1.8.6. Upgrade to 1.8.7+ or `include "backports"`

Comment: @Kiwi: In 1.8.7, a bunch of iterator methods that required blocks in 1.8.6 were modified to return `Enumerator`s when not given blocks.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!  I was under the impression that the documentation was up-to-date, but I don't think it is.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you wish to code-golf/eliminate-duplication for the first example, you can do: `(a = (1..9).step(2).to_a) + a.reverse`. Whether or not this is better will probably depend upon how much C you did in a previous life.

Comment: @Kiwi: Yeah, the doc was quite incomplete with respect to returning enumerators. Fixed for 1.9.2+, but I don't have the courage to backport http://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4afa9e to the 1.8 line.